# Adding a new object to a List replaces all other objects in the List

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with Windows Forms in C# and I have a Character object that's being generated from user input from one form and then passed back into the Main Form via a custom event handler.

The new object is then to be added to a List on the main form. However, when a new item is added to the list on the main form, it also replaces all of the other items in the list, so I end up with a list of all identical objects.

Here's the code where I'm trying to add the new object to the list.

```
private void HandleCharacterCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CharCreatorForm extractForm = sender as CharCreatorForm;
    characterList.Add(extractForm.NewCharacter);

    Debug.WriteLine("NEW LINE");
    foreach (Character character in characterList)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(character);
    }

    SetCharacterCountValue();

    if (CharacterAdded != null)
    {
        CharacterAdded(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

If it helps, here is the block of code from the input form that is then passed back over to the main form to be added to the list.

```
public void CreateCharacter()
{
    newCharacter.Name = nameTextBox.Text;
    newCharacter.Level = levelPicker.Value;
    newCharacter.Race = racePicker.Text;
    newCharacter.Class = classPicker.Text;

    if (goodRadioBtn.Checked == true && evilRadioBtn.Checked == false)
    {
        newCharacter.Alignment = 1;
    }
    else if(evilRadioBtn.Checked == true && goodRadioBtn.Checked == false)
    {
        newCharacter.Alignment = 2;
    }

    newCharacter.ImageIndex = classPicker.SelectedIndex;

    if (CharacterCreated != null)
    {
        CharacterCreated(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    ClearFields();
}
```

Comment: Is a newCharacter variable a global variable? If yes, you're overwriting reference variable, and it's not a bug but a feature, try creating new "NewCharacter" object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateCharacter()` is not newing up a new Character, but rather it is just setting new property values on an existing object.

Since `class` objects are reference objects, you are adding the same "reference" to your list over and over and each time mutating (changing properties) the *single* object in memory that the pointers point at.

Simple fix is to just create a new Character in your `CreateCharacter()` method:

```
public void CreateCharacter()
{
    newCharacter = new Character();  //  <-- here.
    newCharacter.Name = nameTextBox.Text;
    newCharacter.Level = levelPicker.Value;
    newCharacter.Race = racePicker.Text;
    newCharacter.Class = classPicker.Text;

    // ... etc
}
```

Comment: That was it! I can't believe I missed something so simple. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnMack: I suspect that instead of just adding the constructor call as per this answer, it would be better if you removed your `newCharacter` field and instead just used a local variable within the `CreateCharacter` method.